# Arduino - Voltage ladder and analog input pins

Tags: arduino, analog

I have two questions:
1. Does the analog pin on the arduino board get the **voltage** or the **amperage** from the circuit I connect it to? (of course it's scaled to a value from 0 to 1023)

.2. I have this circuit:  http://i60.tinypic.com/fymxwm.png

Assuming you can only turn on one switch at a time (But also if someone turns on more than one switch, I don't want the whole thing to short out), it has a different amperage for each switch.
Now, if the arduino analog pin gets amperage, then I think this is ok.
But if it gets voltage, I've been told to use something called a voltage ladder, as it does the same thing but for voltage, here's my question that I asked before:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/99417/what-resistors-to-use-to-read-several-buttons-with-a-single-analog-pin

And my circuit and the circuit they gave me look pretty similar to me, are they the same?
Will my circuit also change the voltage due to Ohm's law?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The analog in pin measures the voltage. That pin is very high impedance, which means that not much current should flow into or out of that pin. It looks like a very big resistor to ground.

Keep in mind that current is a measure of the amount of charge flowing past a certain point. The voltage is the amount of potential at a certain point.

You also need to know that any time you have 2 equal resistors in series, the voltage at the point in the middle of these two resistors will always be half way between the voltages at the ends. This is a consequence of the series resistance rule that say the total Resistance of resistors in Series is just the sum of the resistors. It also makes intuitive sense.

In your diagram it is not clear where the analog in pin would go. Let's say we put it here...

[image]

In this case, if only the bottom switch is closed, we can figure out what the voltage on the input pin would be by using ratios.

We have 4 equal resistors in series. The value of the Resistors doesn't matter for figuring out the voltage since they are equal.

The total voltage across all the resistors is 5 volts. That 5 volts is Diovided into 4 equal parts by the resistors, so the voltage at each place looks like this...

[image]

...and your ardunio analog input should read 1.25 volts. Try it! You can also use a multimeter to test.

Now lets see what happens when we close the 2nd switch from the bottom. Now the bottom resistor doesn't really matter because all the current will flow though the newly closed switch. Now the 5 volts are divided by 3 equal resistors. Let's see what that looks like...

[image]

Now your ardunio analog input will read about 1.66 volts.

Repeat for the 3rd switch from the bottom and you will get about 2/5 volts at the input because now the current is only flowing though 2 resistors and you are measuring in the middle of them.

Finally, when we close the top switch, now we are effectively connecting the analog in pin directly to the +5 volts at the top of the battery, so you will see about 5 volts.

Make sense?

Now lets look at how you might pick possible values for the resistors. In theory, as long as all the resistors are the same then you will get the same results. In the real world, this is limited by factors including (1) the wire between the resistors has some resistance itself, (2) the analog input actually does let some current flow into it, and (3) there is a limit to how much current that battery can supply while keeping the voltage across it 5 volts.

If you pick too high a value for the resistors, then the little bit of current flowing into the analog in pin will now actually significantly impact the voltage. The input impedance (basically the same as resistance in a case like this where the signal is DC) is for an Ardunio analog input is about 100M ohms. So, if we picked 100M ohms resistors then take the case where the top switch is closed....

[image]

Now the reading We get is 2.5 volts because the (circuit that acts like a ) resistor inside the ardunio is equal to the resistor outside.

If we go to the other extreme and pick values that are very low, now the resistance of the wires will become important. Let's say we pick 1 ohm resistors, you should be able to see now that the wires will be in the same ballpark as the intentional resistors and throw things off that way.

Another important factor is that in this circuit, the current flowing is not really doing any work - it is there just so we can detect the resistors in the path by their effect on the voltage. We want to pick resistors large enough so that no too much current will flow and drain our battery and potentially even make a fire (high current running though a low resistor makes heat).

Turns out that 10K ohms as shown is actually a good value to use. IN the worst case when the top switch is closed, we have 5 volts / 10K ohms = 0.5 milliamps which will not be much of a burden on the battery but will still be big enough that the 100m ohms on the input pin will not even be noticeable.

*Not wasting power*

Take a look at this circuit here...

[image]

Again, all the resistors have the same value (10K in this case) to make things easy.

When all switches are open, the Analog In pin is connected to 0 volts through a resistor and there is no connection to 5 volts, so the input will be very close to 0 volts. Also interesting is that no current will be flowing, so when no switches are closed you don't use any power.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6t4CG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now try closing switch S1. We now have a total of 4 resistors between 5 volts and 0 volts, so they are dividing the 5 volts into 4 parts - each part being 1/4 * 5 volts = 1.25 volts. So, when S1 is closed, the analog in should see 1.25 volts. Note that since the Ardunio gives you a number between 0 and 1023 representing the values between 0 and 5 volts, you should see a value of about 1023 * 1/4 = 255 in your code.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5tdHW.png)</sup>

Next try closing switch S2. Now we have only 3 resistors in between 0 volts and 5 volts, so we should see about 1/3 * 5 volts ~= 1.6 volts on the analog in pin. Switch S1 and Resistor R2 now don't matter anymore. Make sense?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuYLFZ.png)</sup>

Keep going to switch S4 and you'll see that now the input pin is connected almost directly to the 5 volts. The 10K resistor that is also connecting the pin to 0 volts doesn't really matter anymore since the resistance of the wire going to 5 volts is almost zero. Now the analog in pin will see about 5 volts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX8tXX.png)</sup>

At first glance, it might looks like there is a short in the above case where S4 is closed, but let's take a closer look...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHO81Z.png)</sup>

Remember that the analog input pin is "high impedance", which in cases like this basically means that it has very high resistance to the flow of current, on the order of 100M ohms. If we use V=IR with a V of 5 volts and resistance of 100M ohms, we get a current of 50 nano amps. A "nano" is 1 billionth, so you can see that very, very little current Actually flows though the input pin in this Case.

Comment: Many thanks. I still have two questions left: 1. What is the minimum ohm I need for each resistor so things won't fry? (if they will even) and please explain why you chose that value. 2. And what if I connect the analog pin anywhere else? Let's say after the last resistor on the bottom left, will anything change?

Comment: 1) 10K ohms as shown is actually a good value to use. You want to use a relatively large resistor because the bigger the resistor, the less current will flow though it and any current flowing in this circuit is not doing any work so basically just making heat.

Comment: Resistor selection better explained now in answer above. Putting the input in the lower left would not work, becuase that point is connected directly to the 0 volts size of the battery so will always be at zero volts (assuming your resistors are much bigger than the resistance of the wire).

Comment: Wow, thanks. One last question: Assuming I choose to use 10K resistors, and my analog pin has 10 bit resolution, so from 0 to 1023. How do I calculate the values I would get for each switch, assuming I have 15 switches (and resistors) setup in a similar way. Let's say I'm turning on the 9th switch, the calculation would be (9/16 * 1024) = 576 (since the voltage doesn't really matter). Am I right?

Comment: Wait, no, the calculation would be (((1/(9+1) * 5) / 5) * 1024) = 102.4, I can also say the source voltage doesn't matter for my purpose because it cancels out. Am I right now?

Comment: It is more complicated than that in your circuit because pushing a button is changing the total number of resistors and the total resistance, so the values on the analog in are not equally spaced. If you want to know just to learn and satisfy curiosity, I can post an explanation - but if you are looking to really build this then you would probably want a simpler circuit where the voltage values are easier to figure - and one that does not use power except when a button is actually being pushed (yours uses power all the time). Happy to explain either way so lmk which you are looking for.

Comment: I asked my teacher about this, he said I should calclate the ameprage, then I can calculate the voltage. So if I push the third button, I = 5/30k = 1/6 mA. V = I * 20k = 3.333V.
And yes, I do want to build this, what's wrong with my circuit? Oh well I guess that the battery is still draining even while no button is being pushed, what can I do to stop that?

Comment: You can do the full V=IR calculation and get the right answer, but since all resistors are the same value, it is easier to just imagine the resistors dividing the voltage. If you have 2 equal resistors bridging between 0 & 5 volts, then the middle point between them must be at 2.5 volts. If you have 5, then the voltage at the 4 mid-points must be 2,3, & 4 volts.

Comment: "The 10K resistor that is also connecting the pin to 0 volts doesn't really matter anymore since the resistance of the wire going to 5 volts is almost zero. Now the analog in pin will see about 5 volts. " - If the resistance is almost zero, the circuit should short out, shouldn't it? And it will fry my arduino... Should I put a resistor between 5V and S4?

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: The resistance of the wire going to the pin is very low, but remember that the internal resistance of the ardunio input pin is *very* high so almost no current will flow though it.

Comment: so the arduino has like an internal protection against terrible circuit design? fantastic. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: The input pins on the AVR chips used on the ardunios actually do have very robust inputs, but that is not why this works out. I'll add a diagram above...

Answer (score 0):

ADCs usually sense voltage, although, since their input impedance is not infinite, some current will flow into or out of the input, and the resulting current must be taken into account when selecting resistors for a voltage divider ladder.

Your sketch doesn't inidcate how you intend to connect it to the ADC, so ,I can't say if it will work as you intend.